# PHP: Is there a way to override a function, being called by a function I use, without overriding the function itself?

Tags: php, function, inheritance, overriding, redundancy

Consider this:

I am in a package.

I am calling function `a()`.

```
function a (){

...
//do alot of stuff
...

function b ();

....
//do alot of stuff

}
```

All the stuff function a does is perfect and I want to keep it the exact same way. However, I want to change something about function `b()`. Do I have to completly redundantly override function `a()`, the only difference being that it calls overridden function `b()` instead of normal function `b()`. Or is there a cleaner way? (I cannot directly change the way function `b()` behaves and implement some sort of check, since this would be a core modification).

Comment: no, you can not

Comment: Ok, thought so. Thank you teresko!

Comment: Hmm I am not sure if I understand your suggestion correctly. However, if I do, I cant do it, since I can only override but not actually change the functions being called because this would involve a core modification.

Comment: Why do you actually think you need to do this?

Comment: teresko - I am developing for a large existing web application, which has a central system for rendering. I want to create a new page, without changing the core system (for compatibility reasons). I need one of the higher order renderer functions (completly), which calls several lower order functions, which eventually call a function directly rendering a central piece of the site. I only want to override this function, but maintain and keep uniform all the work done by the other rendering functions.

Comment: If those are "functions" and not "object's methods", then there is no way to override them. And even if they were object's methods, it would depend on the exact usage, whether you could apply any overrides.

Comment: As I said, I thought so. Just wanted to double check. This is gonna be one piece of ugly code :D